# How to set jvm memory settings on the node agent in glassfish v2?

Tags: java, glassfish, agent

I m trying to find how to set the jvm memory settings (-Xmx) for the node agent in glassfish v2.

I could not find any option in the admin console under the node agent properties page.

My problem is that the java process without any -Xmx setting will take up to 1/4 of the available memory on the server. That becomes a big problem with a server with a lot of memory.

Does any one know which glassfish config file do I need to modify?

I could not find any thing relevant in the glassfish tree and using JAVA_OPTS env variable did not help.

Comment: I haven't done this but it looks like you could edit startserv (glassfish/nodeagents/{agent.name}/agent/bin.  The last line has the java command on it, and you could change it to pass in JAVA_OPTS, some other variable or just hardcode the memory flag you want.

Comment: And it doesn't answer your question, but Glassfish 3.1 doesn't have node agents any more, which I'm finding to be very nice.

Comment: ...and, how about this? http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19879-01/821-0182/abdjw/index.html  read about INSTANCE-SYNC-JVM-OPTIONS under "Synchronizing Large Applications".  I'm still using GF 2.1 in production, so this is interesting to me.

Answer (score 1):

I  have executed

```
grep -lr '\-Xm' ~/glassfish-3.1.2.2/
```

and this game me result: `~/glassfish-3.1.2.2/glassfish/domains/domain3/config/domain.xml` 
there you can find

```
    <jvm-options>-Xmx512m</jvm-options>
```